# Python - multidimensional array syntax

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array

I am came across `numpy`and am trying to understand the proper syntax for building `multidimensional arrays`. For instance:

```
numpy.asarray([[1.,2], [3,4], [5, 6]])
```

prints:

```
[[ 1.  2.]
 [ 3.  4.]
 [ 5.  6.]]
```

while:

```
numpy.asarray([[1 ,2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
```

prints:

```
[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [5 6]]
```

that `.` is an odd syntax element.

what is it doing exactly?

Comment: setting the `dtype` as floats (with `.`) or ints (without `.`)

Comment: hum. and it could go along any number, like `2.` instead of `1.`, or `3.`, `4.` etc and set the `dtype` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.array` deduces the array shape from the nesting of the `[]`, and `dtype` from the nature of the elements.  If at least one element is a Python float, the whole array is float:

```
In [178]: x=np.array([1, 2, 3.0])    # 1d float
In [179]: x.shape
Out[179]: (3,)
In [180]: x.dtype
Out[180]: dtype('float64')
```

if all elements are integer - the array is also int

```
In [182]: x=np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4]])   # 2d int
In [183]: x.shape
Out[183]: (2, 2)
In [184]: x.dtype
Out[184]: dtype('int32')
```

You can also set the `dtype` explicitly, e.g.

```
In [185]: x=np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4]], dtype=np.float32)
In [186]: x
Out[186]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.]], dtype=float32)
In [187]: x.dtype
Out[187]: dtype('float32')
```